# Proof of Funds for Visiting Canada

Tags: canada, tourist-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm about to visit Canada in 10 days from USA and planning to stay there for about 5 months. I have a multiple entry tourist visa which is valid for 5 years.

Do I still need to provide proof of funds when I arrive there? If yes, how much should it be for something around 5 months? And, should I provide a document for it or is that fine just to have it in my US bank accounts and just show a print of statements?

The reason I ask is that they already asked for the proof of funds when I applied for the Visa last year, but I'm not sure if they also will ask for it when I arrive there or not, and if they will ask proof for a big money as I'm planning to stay there for 5 months?

Comment: No, they will not ask you that (personal experience for USA and Canada)

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to show them proof of funds. As you have mentioned, proof of funds is only asked when you apply for your visa as part of your visa application.

I have been to Canada on a visitor visa four times so far from USA and I was never asked that question. They will just ask you "What is the purpose of your visit and how long and where are you planning to stay?" Be ready to answer these questions.

If you feel restless about it, just have a couple of bank statements of your checking/savings account with you as a back up so that you can travel in peace.

Safe travels :)